# abap insert data to custom table in database using selection screen

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

how to insert data to custom table in db using selection screen?
Is there standard class or method that can be use or need to create custom class?
requirement: after user give the input in the ADD selection-screen page, and hit the button 'add', data will be insert to the respective custom table in db.
How to proceed from here?

```
REPORT YTEST3.

tables YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ.
tables sscrfields.
type-pools : slis.

"DATA: flag TYPE c.

"DATA it_ucomm TYPE TABLE OF sy-ucomm.

TYPES: BEGIN OF TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ, "CREATE STRUCTURE -1

       REQID TYPE YNAH_REQ_ID,
       REQUESTOR TYPE YNAH_REQUESTOR,
       BUSINESS_OWNER TYPE YNAH_BUS_OWN,
       FUNCTIONAL_OWNER TYPE YNAH_FUNC_OWN,
       REQNUM TYPE YNAH_SERVICE_REQ_NUM,
       PROJECT_ID TYPE YNAH_PRO_ID,
       SYSTEM_ID TYPE YNAH_SYS_ID,
       FUNCTIONAL_AREA TYPE YNAH_FUNC_AREA,
       REQUEST_DATE TYPE YNAH_REQ_DATE,
       REQUEST_TIME TYPE YNAH_REQ_TIME,

END OF TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ.

DATA: IT_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ TYPE TABLE OF TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ,
      WA_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ TYPE TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ.

DATA: it_fcat TYPE slis_t_fieldcat_alv.
DATA: wa_fcat TYPE slis_fieldcat_alv.

DATA MYALV TYPE REF TO CL_SALV_TABLE.

DATA MYFUNCTIONS TYPE REF TO CL_SALV_FUNCTIONS_LIST.

DATA MYCOLUMNS TYPE REF TO CL_SALV_COLUMNS_TABLE.


**********SELECTION-SCREENS*********************

*SELECTION-SCREEN FOR RADIO BUTTON 1
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK menu WITH FRAME TITLE text-000.
selection-screen begin of line.
PARAMETER : P_SEARCH RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1 USER-COMMAND ONE DEFAULT 'X'.
selection-screen comment 7(9) for field p_search.
PARAMETER : P_ADD RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1.
selection-screen comment (9) for field p_add.
selection-screen end of line.


*SELECTION-SCREEN FOR RADIO BUTTON 1
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK rad1 WITH FRAME TITLE text-001.
SELECT-OPTIONS:
                s_reqid FOR WA_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ-REQID MODIF ID ONE,
                s_req FOR WA_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ-REQUESTOR NO-EXTENSION NO INTERVALS MODIF ID ONE,
                s_date FOR WA_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ-REQUEST_DATE MODIF ID ONE.
SELECTION-SCREEN: BEGIN OF LINE,
pushbutton 55(12) BUT1 user-command search MODIF ID ONE.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF LINE.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK rad1.

*SELECTION-SCREEN FOR RADIO BUTTON 2
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK rad2 WITH FRAME TITLE text-002.
PARAMETER:
                p_req TYPE TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ-REQUESTOR MODIF ID TWO,
                p_busown TYPE TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ-BUSINESS_OWNER MODIF ID TWO,
                p_funown TYPE TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ-FUNCTIONAL_OWNER MODIF ID TWO,
                p_srvreq TYPE TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ-REQNUM MODIF ID TWO,
                p_proid TYPE TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ-PROJECT_ID MODIF ID TWO,
                p_sysid TYPE TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ-SYSTEM_ID MODIF ID TWO,
                p_funare TYPE TY_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ-FUNCTIONAL_AREA MODIF ID TWO.
SELECTION-SCREEN: BEGIN OF LINE,
pushbutton 55(12) BUT2 user-command add MODIF ID TWO.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF LINE.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK rad2.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK menu.
*---------------------------
AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
*---------------------------
BUT1 = 'SEARCH'.
BUT2 = 'ADD'.
*CLICK OF FIRST RADIO BUTTON
  "IF p_search = 'X'.
    LOOP AT SCREEN.
      IF screen-group1 = 'ONE'.
        IF P_SEARCH = 'X'.
        screen-invisible = '0'.
        screen-active = '1'.
       ELSE.
        screen-invisible = '1'.
        screen-active = '0'.
        ENDIF.
        MODIFY SCREEN.
      ENDIF.
      IF screen-group1 = 'TWO'.
        IF P_ADD = 'X'.
        screen-invisible = '0'.
        screen-active = '1'.
       ELSE.
       screen-invisible = '1'.
       screen-active = '0' .
       ENDIF.
        MODIFY SCREEN.
      ENDIF.
    ENDLOOP.

  at selection-screen. "after processing user input
  case SSCRFIELDS.
    when 'SEARCH'.
      SSCRFIELDS-UCOMM = 'ONLI'.
  endcase.

  "fetch data using select for SEARCH
START-OF-SELECTION.
  SELECT *
    FROM YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ    "Database
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE IT_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ "Into internal table
    WHERE
          REQID in s_reqid and
          REQUESTOR in s_req and
          REQUEST_DATE in s_date.

TRY.
 CALL METHOD CL_SALV_TABLE=>FACTORY
  IMPORTING
    R_SALV_TABLE = MYALV
    CHANGING
      T_TABLE =  IT_YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ.
      CATCH CX_SALV_MSG.
  ENDTRY.
  MYCOLUMNS = MYALV->GET_COLUMNS( ).
  MYCOLUMNS->SET_OPTIMIZE( ).
  MYFUNCTIONS = MYALV->GET_FUNCTIONS( ).
  MYFUNCTIONS->SET_ALL( ).
  CALL METHOD MYALV->DISPLAY.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: currently I tried create custom class and method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `INSERT` or `MODIY` statements in your code. You don't need any custom class for that. Check help for these statements.

```
TABLES YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ.
DATA WA TYPE YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ.
WA-REQID = '1'.
WA-REQUESTOR = p_req.
WA-BUSINESS_OWNER = p_busown.
...<<<add other fields also>>>
INSERT INTO YNAH_CUS_OBJ_REQ VALUES WA.
```